# Laravel 5.6 DataTables proceso del lado del servidor

Tags: laravel, ajax, datatables

Hola comunidad en base a lo que me han respondido me he podido orientar mejor, he modificado mi codigo y todabia no puedo mostrar los registros que deseo en mi datatable tengo 3 tablas users clients companies.
mis relaciones a nivel migracion.

->tabla users:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
```

->tabla clients:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {            
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();                                 
        $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

->tabla companies:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {           
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();                 
        $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('clients')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
}
```

relaciones a nivel de modelos:

->modelo user:

```
public function client()
{       
    return $this->hasOne(Client::class);
}
```

->modelo client:

```
 public function company()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Company::class);
}

public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

->modelo company:

```
public function client()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
}
```

-> mi controlador ClientController:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Client;
use App\Company;
use DataTables;
class ClientController extends Controller 
{        
 public function index()
 {        
    return view('clientes.customers', compact('clientes'));
 }

 public function dataTable()
 {
    $clientes = Client::with(['user.company']);

        return DataTables::eloquent($clientes)
            ->addColumn('action', function($clientes){
                $button = '<button type="button" name="edit" 
                id="'.$clientes->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn- 
                sm">Edit</button>';
                $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                $button .= '<button type="button" name="delete" 
                id="'.$clientes->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn- 
                sm">Delete</button>';
                return $button;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])                
            ->make(true);      
 }
}
```

**Es correcto que pase asi mi variable clientes a mi vista en el metodo index me confundo con la forma tradicional.**

->mi script:

```
<script>
$(function ($) {  

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }          
  });      

  $('#clientes-table').DataTable({        
    responsive  : true,
    processing  : true,
    serverSide  : true,
    ajax        : "{!! route('table.clientes') !!}",                 
    columns:  [
      {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
      {data: 'user.company.registro_fiscal', name: 'user.company.companies.registro_fiscal'},
      {data: 'user.company.nombre', name: 'user.company.companies.nombre'},
      {data: 'user.company.telefono', name: 'user.company.companies.telefono'},
      {data: 'user.company.sitio_web', name: 'user.company.companies.sitio_web'},
      {data: 'direccion', name: 'clients.direccion'},
      {data: 'ciudad', name: 'clients.ciudad'},       
      {data: 'pais', name: 'clients.pais'},
      {data: 'user.company.name', name: 'user.company.users.name'},
      {data: 'telefono_contacto', name: 'clients.telefono_contacto'},
      {data: 'user.company.email', name: 'user.company.users.email'},
      {data: 'action', name: 'Action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
    ]        
  });
```

**no estoy seguro si estoy manipulando de forma correcta los datos en columns data-name**

->mis rutas:

```
Route::group([
'prefix' => 'customers',
'middleware' => 'auth'],
function(){    
 Route::get('/', 'ClientController@index')->name('clientes');       
 Route::get('client', 'ClientController@dataTable')->name('table.clientes');    
});
```

me esta trayendo esto al momento de escribir la ruta manualmente en el navegador (http://roles.local:8080/customers/client):

```
{
 "draw": 0,
 "recordsTotal": 19,
 "recordsFiltered": 19,
 "data": [
   {
    "id": "1",
    "direccion": "Suite 881",
    "ciudad": "Johnsonland",
    "provincia": "Illinois", 
    "codigo_postal": "483",
    "pais": "Afghanistan",
    "telefono_contacto": "1-327-508-5875 x1784",
    "user": null,
    "action": "<button type=\"button\" name=\"edit\" id=\"1\" class=\"edit 
     btn btn-primary btn-sm\">Edit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button 
     type=\"button\" name=\"delete\" id=\"1\" class=\"delete btn btn-danger 
     btn-sm\">Delete</button>"
   },
   {
    "id": "2",
    "direccion": "Apt. 519",
    "ciudad": "Thompsonville",
    "provincia": "Alaska", 
    "codigo_postal": "422",
    "pais": "Mayotte",
    "telefono_contacto": "1-497-415-5362 x7992",
    "user": null,
    "action": "<button type=\"button\" name=\"edit\" id=\"2\" class=\"edit 
     btn btn-primary btn-sm\">Edit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button 
     type=\"button\" name=\"delete\" id=\"2\" class=\"delete btn btn-danger 
     btn-sm\">Delete</button>"
    }
```

**solo me trae de forma correcta los datos de la tabla clients**
`{data: 'direccion', name: 'clients.direccion'},` **y donde aplico mi relacion no los trae.**

Bueno creo que eso es todo me explaye un poco pero necesitaba que me pudieran comprender para darme una mano nose **donde puede estar mi error si en las relaciones o en la forma de pasar mis datos a mi datatable?**
espero su pronta ayuda.
gracias por su tiempo!!

Comment: Te aparece algún error? La consulta de PHP se ejecuta bien?

Comment: @azeos  No me aparece ningun error en la consola. Mi consulta en el controlador se ejecutaba perfecto antes de usar data tables.

Comment: En el controlador estoy pasando correctamente mi variable $clientes al datatables ? Antes hacia un return a la vista usando compact con la variable. Esta ruta llámama correctamente a mi vista blade  Route::get('/', 'ClientController@index')->name('clientes');  y con esta  ruta hago la petición al servidor Route::get('client', 'ClientController@dataTable')->name('table.clientes');   
});  la cual no me trajo ningún dato. Otra duda en mi script no se si estoy definiendo correctamente la propiedad column data ya q es una consulta q relaciona a más de una tabla

Comment: Has cambiado completamente la pregunta, ademas de dar por invalida una respuesta aceptada que es correcta. Tu error ahora es que no hiciste las foráneas bien, apuntas las id entre si en lugar de tener un campo para hacer las foráneas. También tienes mal la llamada de las relaciones, dado que si son relaciones separadas deben ir delimitadas con coma `'user','company'`

Comment: - @Manuel Robles si he reformulado la pregunta no logro entender cuando dices que el error la tengo en las foráneas que apunto las ID entre sí. Lo pensé así por defecto la tabla users ya tiene campos definidos q me sirven, entonces creo una tabla clientes dónde agrego campos solo para clientes y creo una tabla compañías dónde agrego campos para compania (empresa). Entonces una compania(empresa) le pertenece a un cliente y un cliente está relacionado con un usuario ya que no quiero volver agregar el campo nombre apellido e email a la tabla clientes dado q la tabla users ya los trae por defecto

Comment: @Manuel Robles Entonces como plantearia la relacion ahí estaría mi error.?

Comment: Por ejemplo, en company tu funcion `client()` esta buscando en company un `client_id` que no tienes, poque estas generando las foraneas en la migracion mal. Deberias haberlo creado asi `$table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();   
$table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')
            ->onDelete('cascade');;`

Comment: - @Manuel Robles Si revisando la documentación y gracias a tu comentario me pude dar cuenta del error en las migraciones. Bien suponiendo que hasta este punto estaría todo bien. Ahora en mi controlador la llamada a mi relación seria así: $clientes = Client::with(['user', 'company']); ??  Y en mi datatable mostraría los datos asi: columns : [
                {data: 'user.id', name: 'user.users.id'},
                {data: 'company.registro_fiscal', name: 'company.companies.registro_fiscal'}, {data: 'telefono_contacto', name: 'clients.telefono_contacto'} seria la forma correcta de mostrarlos ?

Comment: Casi, pero no, cuando es de la misma tabla del modelo que estas usando, no tienes que nombrarlo, osea tu `clients.telefono_contacto`es simplemente `telefono_contacto`. Se ve muy bien si ves el json que devuelve la request (es muy parecido a hacer un `dd()`)

Comment: OK hasta el momento dudas aclaradas gracias - @Manuel Robles

Comment: @Manuel Robles pregunto: existe la posibilidad de ordenar los registro de manera desc a partir del id ```order : [[0, "desc"]] ```, esto no me esta funcionado lo que busco es que al insertar un registro se posicione primero a partir del id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comenzamos desde principio ya que el código esta muy verde.

Por la sintaxis a suponer que estas en laravel 5.5 o superior y usando la librería de de yajra/datatble.

Laravel usa eloquent y su gestor de relaciones (USALO!!!)

En los modelos creamos las relaciones (yo solo haré una, te dejo [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) todas las posibles)

```
  public function user(){
            return $this->hasOne(Users::class, 'id', 'id');
        }
```

Ahora retocaremos tu consulta del controlador a algo mas simple.

> ```
> $clientes = Client::with(['user.company']); // si es una relación de relación puedes concatenarlas con un punto.
> // Como veras no pongo get(), orderBy(), paginate(), ... dado que lo hará la librería por si sola
> ```

La generación esta bien, puedes usar  DataTables::of($clientes) o DataTables::eloquent($clientes) que ira un pelin mejor.

Ahora en la vista la mitad de los parámetros te sobran

```
$('#clientes-table').DataTable({
            pageLength: 5,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{!! route('table.clientes') !!}",
            dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
            buttons: [],
            "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "Todos"]],
            language: {
                url: '{!! asset('js/plugins/dataTables/traduccion.json') !!}' // Tu archivo de traducciones
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'user.company.registro_fiscal', name: 'user.company.companies.registro_fiscal'},
                ...
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
            ]

        });
```

Con esto deberías tener la tabla en server-side totalmente funcional

Comment: si estoy usuando laravel 5.6 y la libreria yajra/datatable con tu ejemplo lo comprendo mejor durante el día modificare mi código.. revisare las relaciones eloquent para poder implementarlas gracias por tu tiempo!!! @Manuel Robles